# impaired meta participation by linked deleted posts - what can we do about that?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-tools, deleted-posts

Whenever there is a deleted post linked, I personally get the impression that I am actively prevented from useful contributions.

In certain Tags and question milieus it is very difficult to reach the 10k Rep mark in a "reasonable" time.

Thus I would like to propose a feature:

Give a small popup when submitting a meta-post containing a link to a deleted post (on any site), which notifies the poster he has links to deleted posts in his post and should consider adding an image or an uploaded screenshot

Comment: sorry that's not the dupe and I can't find any more the one that was - same request, if a post is linked to from meta let everyone see it.

Comment: Consider the situation where a question is initially not deleted, and then later deleted (self, via 10k vote to delete, via mod delete, via community roomba scripts, via site closure (special case)). Not everyone is initially linking to deleted content.  Additionally, metas typically only have knowledge of their main site (MSO - SO) and no others.

Comment: That isn't a dupe since it's about the mobile site.

Comment: @LanceRoberts also the problem is a whole different one...

Comment: Related: [Make links on meta to deleted questions followable by everyone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210979) /cc @KateGregory

Comment: thanks @JoshCaswell I can no longer vtc because I retracted my inaccurate one, but that's the dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of users active on MSO that can edit such links into the post, so in cases where this is actually useful it tends to happen reasonably quickly.

Adding the deleted post is also not always a good idea. For example, making posts insulting another user publicly available would be counterproductive. In many cases the exact text of the post is not all that important, and a description would be good enough for the meta post. This can also be useful to divorce the meta post somewhat from this one specific post and make it a more general discussion.

In short, I don't think we need to change anything here, if the content of the post are important enough, someone will quickly edit it into the meta post.