# Can we make the distinction between the moderator-tools and moderator-abilities tags more obvious?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

We have two tags for moderation activities here on meta. According to the tag wikis:

[moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) is for

> Tools available to ♦ moderators.

[moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) is for

> a subset of privileges available to moderators and users with high reputation

So, [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) should be for ♦ mod stuff, and [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) is the tag that should be used on questions about 10k and 20k tools.

But [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) is a lot more intuitive than [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) when you're typing in the tags box (and the autocomplete suggestion appears first). So often, questions about 10k and 20k tools get the [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) tag incorrectly. [Some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212535/moderator-tools-bug) [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212445/impaired-meta-participation-by-linked-deleted-posts-what-can-we-do-about-that) [examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211878/rss-feed-for-flags-and-review-queue).

In the interests of full disclosure, the only reason I've noticed this is because questions tagged [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) are dropped into the Teacher's Lounge by a shiny bot. So it may not actually be a real problem. But it is true that, at least with some regularity (3 of the last 15 questions tagged [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools)), users are misunderstanding what this tag is for. Is there anything we can (or should) do about this? Is there a better naming convention we could come up with, or perhaps could we add the ♦ character to the mod tools tag? Or maybe this just needs to be a visual change. The moderator-only tags are that nice bright obvious red color. Though it seems like overkill for this one issue to make an actual UI change to the tag design... I'm just thinking out loud here, really.

Discuss?

Comment: 10k-tools, so similarly 10k-powers